# How to check request content type in ASP.Net Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have trouble finding the way to check request content type in ASP.NET Web Api.  Is there a way I can check request content type whether it is application/xml or application/json at controller level?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a regular:  Request.Content.Headers.ContentType?

Comment: yes but it is giving me a null value all the time.  I thought that should give me content type but it is not then wondering what is the use of that property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a context on every controller: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext.aspx

So you should be able to call `HttpContext.Request.ContentType`.

Comment: So dumb I am.  I was checking Request.Content.Headers property.  I should be using Request.Headers property.  Thanks Erica.

Comment: You really want to avoid using HttpContext as that is only there for compatibility with the ASP.NET runtime.  It won't work in self-host.  Every controller has a Request property that can be accessed directly so the HttpContext option is unnecessary.

Comment: @DarrelMiller thanks - I hadn't realized that. The Request property has the same properties (Headers and ContentType) that HttpContext has, so it should still work the same way.

Comment: How is that selected as the correct answer? The question is about asp.net Web API. The answer is for asp.net MVC.

Comment: you should describe. How to use this?

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is misleading because its answers the question for the MVC paradigm rather than Web API, also pointed out by @ataravati. The following is an example of how to access the ContentType inside of a Web API controller action.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/post")]
public void Post()
{
    var contentType = this.Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
    //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i tried to get ContentType from header by below code.

`var x = this.Request.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First();`
Hope others will get a solution from this.